# What happens on data if prime number used for calculating hash code?

Tags: java, collections, hashcode

I read the Java Generics and Collection book and in that there is one statement

" **prime numbers (such as 31, here) are used in calculating the hash code because multiplying by primes will not tend to shift information away from the low end.**"

What is the meaning of this statement, can anyone help me ?

Comment: If you use an even number the product will have a lower bit which is always 0, this is clearly not as random as it could be.  The same applies for small numbers and non-primes.

Comment: The answer to this question requires some number theory knowledge... you might try asking this on math.stackexchange.com. This is a very good question though.